# how should I invoke super.hashcode with google guava hashCode()

Tags: java, hash, guava, hashcode

```
public abstract class HolidayPackageVariant {
private HolidayPackage holidayPackage;
private String typeHolidayPackage;

@Override
    public int hashCode() {
        return Objects.hashCode(getTypeHolidayPackage(), getHolidayPackage());
    }
}

public final class FlightHolidayPackageVariant extends HolidayPackageVariant{
private Destination originCity;

@Override
    public int hashCode() {
        // need to add super.hashCode() here somehow ?
        return Objects.hashCode(getOriginCity() );
    }
}
```

Google guava hashode(): [Objects.hashCode](http://docs.guava-libraries.googlecode.com/git/javadoc/com/google/common/base/Objects.html#hashCode%28java.lang.Object...%29) works on member objects. How do I specify super class hashCode() in the derived::hashCode() ? I can directly use super.members in the derived class hashCode() function, but if the super.hashCode() changes in any way, that will not be reflected in the derived:hashCode(...).

Comment: Tip for Java 7 and later users, please note from the docs: "Note for Java 7 and later: This method should be treated as deprecated; use Objects.hash(java.lang.Object...) instead."

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Sorry for the non-answer but: this is probably not really what you want to do. *Effective Java* has a long exploration of why subclassing a value type to add an additional value component is a bad idea. In the second edition, it's Item 8, "Obey the general contract when overriding equals." Also see Item 16, "Favor composition over inheritance."

Comment: Lately, someone also suggested me something similar and honestly I feel very confused at this point. I'd appreciate if you can take a look at how/why I arrived at this design. It evolved from a question I asked here: http://programmers.stackexchange.com/questions/140967/how-should-i-design-objects-around-this-business-requirement with this as the backend DB design: http://dba.stackexchange.com/questions/14663/how-do-i-model-this-in-database/14665#14665 and am using `Hibernate` as the ORM. I'd appreciate if you can point me in the right direction.

Comment: I read Item 8, 16 and even 20. I understand the consequences. However, I'd like to point out something in my case: base class HolidayPackageVariant is an `abstract` class, with LandHolidayPackageVariant and FlightHolidayPackageVariant being `final` concrete implementations. I also thought of tagged classes, but from Effective Java, it seems that I am doing the right thing since both variants refer to a `HolidayPackage`, a reference to which is stored in the base class HolidayPackageVariant. What do you think ?

Answer (score 5):

The hashcode is itself an (auto-boxed `Integer`) object, so just include `super.hashCode()` in the objects that make up the hash:

```
public int hashCode() {
    return Objects.hashCode(getOriginCity(), super.hashCode());
}
```

Comment: I took a look at the hashCode function for Objects and it expects object as an argument. Can you explain what do you mean by `hashcode is itself an (autoboxed) object` ?

Comment: hashcode() returns an `int` which will be autoboxed into an `Integer`.

Answer (score 0):

Your class only has one new data member, so there is no need to use `Objects.hashCode(Object...)`.  Try this instead:

```
public int hashCode() {
    Destination oc = getOriginCity();
    return 31 * super.hashCode() + (null == oc ? 0 : oc.hashCode());
}
```

If you have many new data members in the subclass, something like this would also work:

```
public int hashCode() {
    return 31 * super.hashCode() + Objects.hashCode(getOriginCity(), getOtherData(), getMoreData());
}
```